# WCF Service or Windows Service for the Calculation Engine component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-services, scalability, reliability

I have a requirement to create a Rule based Calculation Engine component which has to be invoked from an ASP.Net MVC application. This component will do some calculations based on some rules and can either return the calculated value or put the calculated value in the database. 
This engine also needs to be scaled up or scaled out based on future requirements.
Initially 5 users per day will be requesting this engine to calculate values, but it may increase in future.

So my question is:

- should I create a WCF service for this engine which after invoking returns calculated value
- or, should I create a Windows service which keeps on polling a database table for new calculation requests and after calculation puts the result in a database

Comment: Does the caller require the results of the calculation in a response to their request?

Comment: Have a look at http://hangfire.io

Comment: @TomRedfern I have both the options - to return the result immediately or put the result in the DB, but I need that option which can scale the calculation engine component for future